# OData or Queryable REST?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, odata

Before embarking on API development, looking to choose the right foundation.

So...OData permits queryability over models. Great!

...but REST apis can be decorated with the `[Queryable]` ...

So... what is the remaining advantage of OData over such Queryable APIs?

Maybe the following are true?

- OData routing relies primarily on convention based routing, so not sure one can craft if ever needed to (e.g.: to avoid legacy routes one has to implement?)

- Suspect one cannot query REST APIs based on child entities?

Anything else that would come into play?

Thank you!

Comment: if you use `odatacontroller`, most of your questions should go away

Comment: Thanks TS. I probably was not clear enough. I understand one can make controller by inheriting from odatacontroller to get odata queryability, and its actions will return data wrapped in OData response convention. But queryability is also provided by just using web api, with [queryability] -- just that webAPI doesn't wrap it in Odata wrapper. Its not conformant to OData protocol, but since one gets queryability, so what? Isn't that the main value of OData? Or is there more value to the story?

Comment: The value of OData is that you can provide `GetAll` endpoint and the consumer can use the industry-wide standard [odata] to query your end-point. While you get to relax with no need to create multiple endpoints for each type of search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OData is a *specific* and standardized implementation of *REST*. If you make your standard API endpoint's *queryable* then those specific endpoints will follow *most* of the OData v4 response conventions but it is up to you to document this for the consumers.

When you choose to start from OData, you are choosing to implement the OData conventional standards for *all* of the controllers and *Entities* that you choose to include in the OData Entity Model. This in turn will generate the `$metadata` document that describes the model and the supported functions and actions.

You can add custom *types*, *functions* and *actions* to an OData controller if you follow the conventions correctly. You can also directly host standard API controller endpoints if you want to, but unless you register them with the OData model, they will not be included in the `$metadata` document.

You could choose to replicate or implement the entire OData specification in your API from first principals if you want to, including producing your own `$metadata` document... But if you were going to go to all that trouble then it would have been far easier to just use the `ODataController` and implement OData properly.

Making the decision to use OData over standard Web API is usually driven by your chosen documentation method and if you can accept the general OData query conventions and if the consumers of the API can understand OData. OData standards are clearly defined so that you don't have to worry as much about educating consumers on *how* to use your API and can focus more on the implementation itself.

Comment: Really excellent answer. Appreciate your making the distinction that code wise, you get near equivalencies, but even if you never have to put in the design and dev effort to work out solutions to edge cases, there is a documentation/comms cost to not following a standard. Thanks!